# Browsers don't respond to Taskbar's context menu

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Running Win8.1 RTM with patched-to-current copies of Chrome, IE, and Firefox. Attempting to start any in private/incognito mode by right-clicking and choosing the given context menu item will fail silently. No error, nothing left in the Event log - just no resulting window.

CommandLine **iexplorer -private** and **firefox -private** (haven't found Chrome start-up switch yet) *will* work.

I'm the sole user of the workstation - running as Admin - only working with Desktop apps (not metro) - no reason to suspect infection. puzzled.

ADDENDUM: Turns out the that most of the choices offered at the 'RightClick From Taskbar' for all three browser apps will do nothing. For example - the only context menu item for chrome that works is the one that literally opens Chrome (and unpin from taskbar). None of the others will execute *anything*. Doesn't matter if Chrome is already open or not - nothing happens. Firefox = same misbehavior.

IE's 'Frequent' items *will* respond (opens the given URL) but nothing in 'Tasks'.